# Script font for writing a constitution?

Tags: font-recommendation, microsoft-office

I am stuck on what script font to use for my fictional constitution. I thought first of Edwardian Script since that looks a lot like fancy handwriting but the built in double space between the letter right before the apostrophe and the apostrophe discouraged me from using it.

I would prefer to use a handwriting type font that is built into the office 365 on windows 10 that isn't Edwardian Script.

I am using OpenOffice to write this document so I might have to install the font onto my computer since I don't have Microsoft Office(it costs $80 or so to buy Microsoft Office and I am not paying that price just for doing what I already can do with OpenOffice for free) but since my Momma would be looking at it, it would be nice if I could just email her the document and not have to give her a link to a free font download in that email.

I don't have to worry about compatibility because OpenOffice can open .doc(Microsoft Word format) files and Microsoft Word can open .odt(OpenOffice Writer format) files.

But is there any fancy handwriting type font that is built into Office 365 on Windows 10 that does not have increased space before the apostrophe(that increased space to me just looks wrong)? I specifically want a script font so that it looks like cursive handwriting.

Comment: Have you considered the option of sharing the document as a PDF? That way you could use any font that you like and the person viewing the file wouldn't need to have the font installed.

Comment: If you are looking for script-like free fonts, dafont(dot)com has loads. Then as others have said, save as PDF. You don't need office for this. OpenOffice can save PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

The font [American Scribe](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/3ip/american-scribe/) is made to resemble the handwriting in the constitution, and in fact [P22 Declaration](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/p22/declaration/) was conceived to be an absolute copy, including the sizes etc.

The problem is both of those are commercial fonts, and I understand that budget is a concern.

The good news is that [US Declaration](http://www.dafont.com/us-declaration.font) (see below) is free (like speech I guess haha)

[image]

So I recommend that you use this typeface, and then from Open Office export as a PDF to email out:

File menu > Export as PDF

Answer (score 0):

US Declaration is free for personal use, but the designer requests you send him an email if you want to use it for commercial use, presumably to make a financial deal to use it.